# How can I trigger a GitHub Actions workflow from another GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have a GitHub Action workflow that is triggered on a `push` or `pull_request` event. I have second GitHub Action that is triggered on a `workflow_dispatch` event. I want to trigger the second action from the first...

In my action yaml file, I have

```
permissions:
  actions: write
```

I also have a step like

```
      - name: Run second action
        run: |
          curl -L \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/$org/$repo/actions/workflows/$workflow_id/dispatches \
            -d "{\"ref\": \"${{ github.ref }}\"}"
```

This uses the API to invoke the `workflow_dispatch` event against the second action.

The problem I am having is passing the right `ref` value to the action in the POST body. I am getting the error `"message": "No ref found for: refs/pull/1392/merge"`.

Any suggestion for getting the right value for the `ref`? The checkout step seems to be getting `refs/remotes/pull/1392/merge`?

Comment: Why not `workflow_call` and [`uses: path/to/second-workflow.yml`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow)?

Comment: I don't want to use that pattern because the workflows in question do integration testing and can run for 20 minutes or more. I want them to kick off in parallel.

Comment: Why not just give the same trigger, or have parallel jobs within one workflow?

Comment: I have it set up right now with the same triggers. And it works ok. But the triggers are complex (lists of files and directories) and I don't like defining those in multiple places. I want to define those lists of changed files in one place, then have all the different tests kick off.

Comment: Why not mention this problem you're trying to solve in the question? _"...or have parallel jobs"_ (one of which can still use a reusable workflow).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the docs of https://github.com/benc-uk/workflow-dispatch#ref.  I need to call the workflow through the API like this:

```
          curl -L \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/$org/$repo/actions/workflows/$workflow_id/dispatches \
            -d "{\"ref\": \"${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref || github.ref }}\"}" \
            --fail-with-body
```

The `ref` value in a pull request is `github.event.pull_request.head.ref`.